# How to Change zoom settings on Chrome with using Python Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't adjust the zoom and zoom settings in Chrome. Normally in chrome, `ctrl and -` zooms out and `ctrl and +` zooms in. Why doesn't this work in selenium?

I Try this; Not working.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "+")
actions.perform()
```

and this is not working too;

```
browser.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='flex--item fl1 fs-headline1']").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "+")
```

This code is working but not good for me. Because this code breaks the layout of the page;

```
browser.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='67%'")
```

I want to zoom in and out from chrome settings. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Question is: why?

Comment: I actually put the title like this to be open to any ideas on how to do it. There must be a way.

Comment: Again: but why? Selenium is for using websites like user would. Why would you need to see what's in there, when all the work is done by the code anyway? After automating and debugging, one usually makes the browser headless, not seeing the window at all. So why zoom?

Comment: Sorry about that. actually I want to zoom out. Selenium only sees the portion that appears on the screen. If I can zoom out the sections I need become visible and I can get the data without scrolling down. Is not it?

Comment: Selenium can see everything that is displayed, as long as you correctly put in the class name or id name to find it. If you want to click something (as opposed to scraping url and accessing it that way; eg some javascript buttons or links), it just cannot be behind some other object (eg annoying cookie monits if you're in EU)

Comment: hmm, this is what i want to do; now when i go to the top of this page, add comment button is not visible, without scrolling down selenium can't see it. When I zoom out 75%, the add comment button appears and selenium sees it. Am I wrong?